# JSON.parse error for single quote in json encoded string

Tags: javascript, json

JSON.parse is giving error `Unexpected end of Json data` on this json encoded string which contain single quotes

`[{"size":"20cm\/S","characters_cost":[{"characters":"~!@#$%\"'","cost":"78"}]}]`

```js
const json = document.querySelector('#cCalc').textContent;
const array = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="hidden" id="cCalc" value="[{"size":"20cm\/S","characters_cost":[{"characters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789","cost":"42"},{"characters":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","cost":"48"},{"characters":"~!@#$\"'","cost":""}]},{"size":"25cm\/M","characters_cost":[{"characters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789","cost":"52"},{"characters":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","cost":"60"}]},{"size":"30cm\/L","characters_cost":[{"characters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789","cost":"62"},{"characters":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","cost":"71"}]},{"size":"38cm\/XL","characters_cost":[{"characters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789","cost":"75"},{"characters":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","cost":"86"}]}]">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsonlint.com says it's fine.

Comment: Show how you're assigning the string.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/codogoxide/1/edit?html,js,console,output — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Please check https://jsbin.com/siqifiboci/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @AtulSharma — *Edit the question* to include the [mcve]. (And your problem in that example has nothing to do with JSON. Do some basic debugging. Log the variables you are dealing with.)

Comment: Try with this string: `[{"size":"20cm\/S","characters_cost":[{"characters":"~!@#$%\\"\'","cost":"78"}]}]` . So with escaping the " and ' symbols in the `characters` field.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `cCalc` is an input, it doesn't have `.textContent`. You should use `.value` to get the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **value** attribute is not correctly sanitized:

[image]

You first need to HTML-entity encode the attribute contents, and then you will be able to correctly parse the JSON on the client.

Comment: Yes html entity encode solved the issue.

htmlspecialchars($json_string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems.

1. `textContent` gives you the text in the child nodes of an element. An `input` is a void element. It has no child nodes. It's value can be read with the `value` property.
2. Your HTML is invalid. You are trying to use raw `"` characters in the value attribute's value, but that value is delimited with `"` so the first one marks the end of the value. You need to express them as `&quot;` instead of `"`

Such:

```js
const textContent = document.querySelector('#cCalc').textContent;
const json = document.querySelector('#cCalc').value;
const array = JSON.parse(json);
console.log({textContent, json, array});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="hidden" id="cCalc" value="[{&quot;size&quot;:&quot;20cm\/S&quot;,&quot;characters_cost&quot;:[{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;42&quot;},{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;48&quot;},{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;~!@#$\&quot;'&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]},{&quot;size&quot;:&quot;25cm\/M&quot;,&quot;characters_cost&quot;:[{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;52&quot;},{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;60&quot;}]},{&quot;size&quot;:&quot;30cm\/L&quot;,&quot;characters_cost&quot;:[{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;62&quot;},{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;71&quot;}]},{&quot;size&quot;:&quot;38cm\/XL&quot;,&quot;characters_cost&quot;:[{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;75&quot;},{&quot;characters&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&quot;,&quot;cost&quot;:&quot;86&quot;}]}]">
</body>
</html>
```